# I am not able to put a lightning component in a VF page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <script>
    var accountId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
        $Lightning.use("c:aimiaLgtrichTextInputapp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:aimiaLgtrichTextInput",
               {},
                "myVal",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
            });
    </script>
    <div id="myVal"></div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: try by adding <apex:includeLightning /> tag in vf

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your app is globally accessible (i.e: extends `ltng:outApp`) and create a dependency for the components it uses.

```html
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:aimiaLgtrichTextInput"/>
</aura:application>
```

Then you can call it on the visualforce page using the code bellow:

```html
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="myVal" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:aimiaLgtrichTextInputapp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:aimiaLgtrichTextInput",
          { /*add your parameters, probably accountId*/ },
          "myVal",
          function(cmp) {
              console.log("Component created!");
              console.log(cmp);
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

It's probably safer to put the containing div ABOVE the scrip (so when the script is read it can find the div Id)